# Text string using Biopython

Tags: biopython

I'm using Biopython in my code and i need to extract the abstract out of articles. For searching the article I'm using the function:

```
def search(query):
Entrez.email = 'your.email@example.com'
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                        sort='relevance',
                        retmax='20',
                        retmode='xml',
                        term=query)
results = Entrez.read(handle)
return results
```

I'm looking for the simpliest way to get the text as a string after searching the article (I'm aiming just for one result in a search using the pmid).
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try use [metapub](https://github.com/metapub/metapub):

```
from metapub import PubMedFetcher

fetch = PubMedFetcher()
article = fetch.article_by_pmid('31326596')
article.abstract
```