# BioPython Entrez article limit

Tags: biopython, ncbi

I've been using the classic article function which returns the articles for a string

```
from Bio import Entrez, __version__

print('Biopython version : ', __version__)

def article_machine(t):
    Entrez.email = 'email'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                            sort='relevance',
                            retmax='100000',
                            retmode='xml',
                            term=t)
    return list(Entrez.read(handle)["IdList"])

print(len(article_machine('T cell')))
```

I've noticed now that there's a limit to the amount of articles I receive (not the one I put in retmax).
The amount I get is 9999 PMIDS, for key words who used to return 100k PMIDS (T cell for example)

[image]
The amount I get now

[image]
The amount I used to get

I know it's not a bug in the package itself but in NCBI.
Has someone managed to solve it?

Comment: still need a solution

Comment: Any luck with that? It is so annoying that you cannot even get the full (>10,000) list of IDs anymore.

Comment: nope, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

from : [The E-utilities In-Depth: Parameters, Syntax and More](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch)

> retmax

> Total number of UIDs from the retrieved set to be shown in the XML output (default=20). By default, ESearch only includes the first 20 UIDs retrieved in the XML output. If usehistory is set to 'y', the remainder of the retrieved set will be stored on the History server; otherwise these UIDs are lost. Increasing retmax allows more of the retrieved UIDs to be included in the XML output, up to a maximum of 10,000 records.

> To retrieve more than 10,000 UIDs from databases other than PubMed, submit multiple esearch requests while incrementing the value of retstart (see Application 3). For PubMed, ESearch can only retrieve the first 10,000 records matching the query. To obtain more than 10,000 PubMed records, consider using  that contains additional logic to batch PubMed search results

Unfortunately my code devised on the above mentioned info, doesnt work:

```
from Bio import Entrez, __version__

print('Biopython version : ', __version__)

def article_machine(t):
    
    all_res = []
    
    Entrez.email = 'email'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                            sort='relevance',
                            rettype='count',
                            term=t)
    number = int(Entrez.read(handle)['Count'])
    
    print(number)
    
    retstart = 0
    
    while retstart < number:
        
        retstart += 1000
        
        print('\n retstart now : ' , retstart ,' out of : ', number)
        
        Entrez.email = 'email'
        handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                                sort='relevance',
                                rettype='xml',
                                retstart = retstart,
                                retmax = str(retstart),
                                term=t)
        
        all_res.extend(list(Entrez.read(handle)["IdList"]))
                       

    return all_res


print(article_machine('T cell'))
```

changing `while retstart < number:` with `while retstart < 5000:`

the code works, but as soon as **retmax** exceeds 9998, that is using
the former while loop needed to access all the results,  I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Search Backend failed: Exception:
'retstart' cannot be larger than 9998. For PubMed, 
ESearch can only retrieve the first 9,999 records 
matching the query.
 To obtain more than 9,999 PubMed records, consider 
using EDirect that contains additional logic 
to batch PubMed search results automatically
 so that an arbitrary number can be retrieved.
 For details see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/
```

See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/ that actually should be https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/?report=reader

Try to have a look at NCBI APIs to see if there is something could work out your problem usinng a Python interface, I am not an expert on this , sorry : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/developers/

Comment: thank you for the replay, I'm not sure how to preform the last sentence

Comment: Add a retstart to your request, after you get the number of hits, and increment it by the max limit allowed with every new request untill you reach the number of hits. Cant try any code now. Please add your code in text format instead of images, coild be easier to people that want to help to generate code

Comment: To get the number of hits run the query with rettype = 'counts' parameter that should return the number of hits available in the database as per your request

Comment: my idea doesnt work retstart needs to be less than 9998 see updated answer, sorry mate !  maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/71381100/9877065 metapub is the way to go ??

Comment: yeah ive just tried the restart and it doesnt actually work, i will try the second solution though